# Firebase admin sdk with java doesn't connect

Tags: java, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to use firebase database to create a java desktop RMI data management system. My first step was to confirm the connectivity of firebase using the admin sdk. I followed the step in the guide exactly as it is and got no progress. the program executes, but there is no data modification in my firebase console.

following is the code i have so far..

```
public class Main{

    public static class User2 {

        public String date_of_birth;
        public String full_name;
        public String nickname;

        public User2(String dateOfBirth, String fullName) {
            this.date_of_birth = dateOfBirth;
            this.full_name = fullName;
        }

        public User2(String dateOfBirth, String fullName, String nickname) {
            this.date_of_birth = dateOfBirth;
            this.full_name = fullName;
            this.nickname = nickname;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
        try {

            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("rathnapuralabs-firebase-adminsdk-okzic-f6313557b4.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FirebaseOptions options = null;
        try {

            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://rathnapuralabs.firebaseio.com")
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference();

        DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users2");

        Map<String, User2> users = new HashMap<>();
        users.put("alanisawesome", new User2("June 23, 1912", "Alan Turing"));
        users.put("gracehop", new User2("December 9, 1906", "Grace Hopper"));

        usersRef.setValueAsync(users);

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();
               System.out.println(document);
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
           }
    });
    }
```

this code give me three 3 lines of errors.

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

but something tells me that even with these errors the data still should be saved to the firebase.

following is the github link to the codes and the key json.

https://github.com/bandarawaththa/Testing-Firebase-with-realtime-db.git

Comment: the errors are for improper configuration of sl4j logger, you can ignore it for now as it has nothing to do with the actual operation

Comment: @Kushan i thought so too.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
try {
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials
                                    .fromStream(new ClassPathResource("/firebase-authentication.json").getInputStream()))
                    .build();

            if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The "/firebase-authentication.json" is in the resources folder.

Comment: i tried it and still does not work. these codes are very similer.. so i think both of them should work.. my code is also from the firebase guide.. can you please take a look at the project from github personally and maybe you can show me your project if you do not mind.

Comment: I used my project only to test Firebase Auth. Don't know if it would be useful for you. But you use your own firebase-authentication file right?

Comment: you are talking about the json file right. yes, i have it

Comment: Your pom.xml file is missing on github. could you provide it?

Comment: I dont have such a file.. do i need to create it

Comment: How do you load your dependencies for Firebase?

Comment: I made my test project public on gitlab. Maybe that helps. https://gitlab.com/JoeBeer/spring-boot-and-angular-demo/tree/master/server

Comment: File -> project structure -> libraries -> Download library from maven repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198309/discussion-between-eshaka-and-constantin-beer).